# Join on DATETIME field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

Here is my example. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e88e/15)

First of all I do not understand why it causes an error.

Secondly, I would expect it to return `2011-10-11 00:00:00`.

I already read on the Internet that joining on `DateTime` columns is not easy, but I would like to understand why.

Regards,

Comment: Invalid column name 'TempField'.: SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Table1.DateTimeField)) as TempField from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table2.DateTimeField = Table1.TempField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is because you are joining on an Alias. the  *SELECT* part of the statement (where the alias is applied) is actually one of the last operations to be performed, after the engine has performed a join, so the alias cannot be used in the join.  Try the below, and join on the actual expression

```
SELECT 
   DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Table1.DateTimeField)) as TempField 
FROM 
   Table1 
INNER JOIN 
   Table2 ON Table2.DateTimeField = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Table1.DateTimeField))
```